# Install office online for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, oos

I am going to install the office online for SharePoint 2016

What are the considerations that I should take care during installation?
Is it need independent server?

Can I install the workflow manager on the same office online server?is it supported? Will it effect on performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be own server product on the server.

- No other Server Application should be installed on it.
- No Office version should be installed on Office Online Server.
- Don’t Install OOS on the Domain Controller.

[Tips And Tricks For Office Online Server Deployment In SharePoint 2016](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/tips-and-tricks-for-office-online-servers-deployment-in-sharepoint-2016/)

[Plan Office Online Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/plan-office-online-server)

You can install Workflow Manager along with SharePoint on same server but should not be with OOS.

Comment: Thanks waqas, what do you mean with no other application server should be installed on it?

Comment: Is it a SharePoint server in the farm? Or independent one? How it works with the SharePoint farm?

Comment: i mean, if you install OOS on Server A, on that server their should not be any other server application i.e SharePoint, exchange Workflow Manager etc. 
Once you install the OOS then you have to connect to your SharePoint farm, just check the both links in my answer.